# Springboot + jpa hibernate + myslq caching writes

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

Apologies that I am working with inherited code and don't understand it well enough to create a minimal reproducible example.

The application is saving data to a MySQL database, through a JPA repository.

The application works, but the data is not apparent through a second application (eg DBeaver) until the MySQL server is restarted.

Is there something I need to set in MySlq (5.6.21) or is there some way I should be configuring the connection in my application to change this behavior?

I have the following in my application.yml:

```yaml
spring:
  lifecycle:
    timeout-per-shutdown-phase: 5s
  datasource:
    password: MYPASS
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useServerPrepStmts=true
      &rewriteBatchedStatements=true&cachePrepStmts=true
    username: MYUSER
    auto-commit: true
    hikari:
      auto-commit: true
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      use-new-id-generator-mappings: false
      connection:
        provider_disables_autocommit: false
```

Comment: Why are you using auto-commit?

Comment: I think the last developer may have played with it to work around this issue. I tried adding more such flags as it doesn’t seem like it is committing the data.

Comment: Remove the auto-commit and how the code how you save the entity